# Search multiple fields using elastic search + rails

Tags: elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5

I have Record model with state(integer) and date_of_dervice_provided(date) fields.

I want to perform a search based on below two fields.

1) enum state: [:created, :valued, :signed, :approved] 
2) date_of_dervice_provided

**I am able to search using ActiveRecord rails as below.**

`@records = Record.all`

`@records = @records.where(state: params[:state]) if params[:state]`

`@records = @records.where('extract(year  from date_of_service_provided) = ?', params[:year]) if params[:year]`

**I want to search it using elastic search**

To implement elastic search, I've have added things as below

**Gemfile**

`gem 'elasticsearch-model'`

`gem 'elasticsearch-rails'`

**Record.rb** model file

`require 'elasticsearch/model'`
`include Elasticsearch::Model`
`include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks`

`settings do
    mappings dynamic: false do
      indexes :state, type: 'integer'
      indexes :date_of_service_provided, type: 'date'
    end
  end`

I am little much familiar with the elastic search. I am able to search using elastic search as below

`@elastic_records = Record.all
@elastic_records = @elastic_records.search(params[:state])`

## **I want to perform search based on two fields by using elastic search.**